# Unity application gets stuck within a Docker container but works on host

Tags: docker, unity-game-engine

An unity application (linux/amd64), not the editor, that I run **inside** a Docker container just **stops silently at the point before `Initialize engine version: 2021.3.22f1 (b6c551784ba3)`**.

The full and healthy output whenn I run it **outside** a container looks like this:

```
vik@r1g:/mnt/c/Users/vik/Downloads/test-server/server-headless-230620-1057$ ./server-headless-230620-1057
[UnityMemory] Configuration Parameters - Can be set up in boot.config
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-count=1"
    "memorysetup-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-gfx-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-gfx-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-cache-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-typetree-allocator-block-size=2097152"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-count=1"
    "memorysetup-profiler-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-profiler-editor-allocator-block-size=1048576"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-main=4194304"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size=2097152"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size-background=1048576"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-reduction-small-platforms=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-background-worker=32768"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-job-worker=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-preload-manager=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-nav-mesh-worker=65536"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-audio-worker=65536"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-cloud-worker=32768"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-gfx=262144"
Mono path[0] = '/mnt/c/Users/vik/Downloads/test-server/server-headless-230620-1057/server-headless-230620-1057_Data/Managed'
Mono config path = '/mnt/c/Users/vik/Downloads/test-server/server-headless-230620-1057/server-headless-230620-1057_Data/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
Preloaded 'lib_burst_generated.so'
Preloaded 'libenet.so'
Initialize engine version: 2021.3.22f1 (b6c551784ba3)
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path /mnt/c/Users/vik/Downloads/test-server/server-headless-230620-1057/server-headless-230620-1057_Data/UnitySubsystems
Forcing GfxDevice: Null
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=0; jobified=0
NullGfxDevice:
    Version:  NULL 1.0 [1.0]
    Renderer: Null Device
    Vendor:   Unity Technologies

and so on...
```

When I run the same application **inside** a docker container it goes like this and just sits there. The process stays alive.

```
2023-06-21 10:44:41 [UnityMemory] Configuration Parameters - Can be set up in boot.config
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-size=4194304"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-count=1"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-gfx-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-gfx-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-cache-allocator-block-size=4194304"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-typetree-allocator-block-size=2097152"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-size=4194304"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-count=1"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-profiler-allocator-block-size=16777216"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-profiler-editor-allocator-block-size=1048576"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-main=4194304"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size=2097152"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size-background=1048576"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-reduction-small-platforms=262144"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-background-worker=32768"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-job-worker=262144"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-preload-manager=262144"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-nav-mesh-worker=65536"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-audio-worker=65536"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-cloud-worker=32768"
2023-06-21 10:44:41     "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-gfx=262144"
2023-06-21 10:44:41 Mono path[0] = '/home/twindrums/server-headless-230425-0757/server-headless-230425-0757_Data/Managed'
2023-06-21 10:44:41 Mono config path = '/home/twindrums/server-headless-230425-0757/server-headless-230425-0757_Data/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
2023-06-21 10:44:41 Preloaded 'lib_burst_generated.so'
2023-06-21 10:44:41 Preloaded 'libenet.so'
2023-06-21 10:44:41 Unable to preload the following plugins:
2023-06-21 10:44:41 libsentry.so
```

What I tried so far:

- Different docker base images (debian, ubuntu, stable, slim, ...)
- Different Unity versions
- Moving the application manually to the container after it has been running (with the same result)
- Removing all kinds of extra packages we have
- Unity Dedicated Server build and Headless version (with -batchmode -nographics)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem as you do when I was using Rancher Desktop as my docker client. After I switched back to Docker Desktop, the problem disappears.